# Partial completion of subspaces of Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Assume $H$ is a Hilbert space and $H_1\subset H$ and $H_2 \subset H$ are (closed) subspaces with $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{0\}$.

Is there an $H_3 \subset H$, such that $H = H_1 \oplus (H_2 \oplus H_3)$ ?

If $H$ was finite dimensional, $H_3$ could be chosen as the orthogonal complement to $H_1 \cup H_2$. Is this also legit in infinite dimensions?

Comment: It can happen that $H_1+H_2$ is not closed.

Comment: If your $\oplus$ means orthogonal sum or topological direct sum, then not always as $H_1\oplus H_2$ need not even be closed. If it simply means algebraic direct sum, then yes by basis completion.